# android: setImageResource on Imagebuttons inflated to a view

Tags: android, imagebutton, layout-inflater

I would like to inflate imagebuttons programmatically to a linearlayoutm, coded as follows:

### Code:

```
public void set_keyboard_words(int row, int start, int end) 
    { 
        for (int p = start; p <= end; p++)
        {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btn_ball_sq,btn_ball_sq);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            keyboard_btn = new ImageButton(this);
            keyboard_btn.setId(p);
            final int id_ = keyboard_btn.getId();
            keyboard_btn.setImageResource(BUTTON_IMG[p-1]);
            keyboard_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_selector);
            keyboard_btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            keyRow1.addView(keyboard_btn, params);
            keyboard_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {           
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                    button_action(id_);
                }
            });
        }   
    }
```

### Xml:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/keyRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:splitMotionEvents="false" >
            </LinearLayout>
```

### Background:

The imagebuttons are some balls.

The imagebuttons could be inflated to the  linearlayout `keyRow1`.

However, I do not know how to set the image resources to the imagebuttons correctly. The balls inflated are so small instead of fitting to XY of the buttons.

**Screenshot as follows:**

1. If image set as `keyboard_btn.setImageResource(BUTTON_IMG[p-1]);` (with blue backgrounds as BackgroundResource for seeing the actual size of button), the balls are very small

[image: setImageResource]

2. If image set as `keyboard_btn.setBackgroundResource(BUTTON_IMG[p-1]);`, the size is now proper but the actual backgroundResource cannot be set anymore

[image]

### Question:

I would like to use the method of `setImageResource` for the imagebuttons as the button background would later be changed to other background image upon pressed.

How could I set the imagebutton's image using setImageResource but with size of balls similar to the 2nd screenshot??

Comment: what is the value for btn_ball_sq in params?

Comment: it was defined as screen_width / 10 (i.e. the imagebutton are in square with height and width  = 1/10 of screenwidth) , and the balls are 100x100px

Comment: in case 1, the balls even become oval, while it should be a straight circle as in case 2

Answer (score 0):

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        keyboard_btn = new ImageButton(this);
        keyboard_btn.setId(p);
        final int id_ = keyboard_btn.getId();
        keyboard_btn.setImageResource(BUTTON_IMG[p-1]);
        keyboard_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_selector);
    keyboard_btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Just try the above code, if the image doesn't shrink then you need to optimize the image based on the width you get for each button from screen width.

Comment: the ball images still shink just like case 1.: with the imagebutton boarder height and width adjusted to wrap_content, but the balls are still very small as in case 1